# Why is my custom validator not updating my FormControl?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Redux-SPA with a Messaging System with mailboxes (basically just folders). When the user wants to create a new mailbox (folder), a dialog gets shown where the user can enter a new mailbox name. To prevent unnecessary API calls, I look into the state to see if the mailbox/folder does already exist. If yes, I want to invalidate the form and disable the "Create" button.

I have already made sure that the function returns the correct values via the `tap()`. The control is invalidated correctly if it is empty, so the default validator works correctly. Just my custom validator is not working somehow.

Where is my error? What can I try to debug further?

This is my code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-mailbox-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'new-mailbox-dialog.component.html',
})
export class NewMailboxDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  formControl: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required], this.mailboxNameExists.bind(this));

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewMailboxDialogComponent>,
    private messagingFacade: MessagingFacade
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  mailboxNameExists(control: FormControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.messagingFacade.getMailboxesList$.pipe(
      tap(() => console.log(control.value)),
      map(names => names.find(mailbox => mailbox.designation === control.value)),
      map(exists => exists ? { mailboxNameExists: true } : null)
      tap(value => console.log(value)),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the console output for the existing mailbox named "Test"
[image]

Comment: can you share how you have declared this.messagingFacade.getMailboxesList$

Comment: Is the api call in the validator actually being called?  Sort of looks like you are not subscribing

Comment: @Randy I am not sure where I would have to subscribe. The official Angular documentation does say something about subscribing either. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms

Comment: I am not saying you need to call subscribe, poor wording on my part.  Just asking if this code is being reached?

Your code may work with a take(1) in it, it has other issues which I address below with my answer with the debounce, distinct, and the switchmap.

The bebounce will keep it from executing to many times, the distinct will keep it from running on the same input twice, and the switchmap will kill any previous call that has not completed when new input happens.

Mr Stash and my answer have everything that should help here.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I usually write my AsyncValidatorFn streams/method as follows:

```
validator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      if (!control.value || control.pristine) {
        return of(null);
      }
      
      return control.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        take(1),
        switchMap(value => {
          return this.messagingFacade.getMailboxesList$;
        }),
        catchError(err => of(null)),
        map(response => {
            return response ? { error: true } : null;
          }),
        finalize(() => {
          control.markAsTouched();
          this.ref.markForCheck();
        })
      );
    };
  }
```

Not sure you need the finalize, I have this usually do to the detection strat.

Also in the template, which you do not show I am normally checking for touched and invalid along with the errors to show the error message.

Comment: Thank you. In the template I am currently only checking for validity. I will try this.

Comment: I get the error "Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'NewMailboxDialogComponent'": Where do you declare it?

Comment: That is the injected ChangeDetectorRef

Answer (score 0):

The 'complete' method of the observable needs to be called for the validation to be triggered.

Assuming you are using a subject or a similar observable where the complete method does not get called by default, the stream remains open and thus the validation does not get triggered.

A few ways to resolve this problem are

##### 1. Using the `of` method, where the complete method gets called by default.

MessagingFacade TS:

```js
mailboxesList = [{designation: 'test'}]
getMailboxesList$ = of(this.mailboxesList)
```

##### 2. Manually calling the `complete` method in the observable.

MessagingFacade TS:

```js
mailboxesList = [{designation: 'test'}]
getMailboxesList$ = new Observable((subscriber) => {
    subscriber.next(this.mailboxesList);
    subscriber.complete();
  });
```

##### 3. Using the `take` operator to unsubscribe, which will end the stream and trigger the validation.

Component TS:

```js
return this.messagingFacade.getMailboxesList$.pipe(
  map((names: any[]) =>
    names.find((mailbox) => mailbox.designation === control.value)
  ),
  map((exists) => (exists ? { mailboxNameExists: true } : null)),
  take(1)
);
```

Comment: What does "of" do here?

Comment: is getMailboxesList$ setup as a behaviour subject?

Comment: I am not sure what that is. Its an observable you get from the Facade

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check if any one of the solutions work